# BASH: Recursive design, linear implementation

Tags: bash, recursion, design-patterns, wait

### The idea

Say I have a few scripts. For example:

```
script1
script2
script3
```

I want each script to:

1. Do something
2. Run next script
3. Wait
4. Cleanup

The `wait` is simply to wait for the next script to complete.

### The problem

A recursive solution is rather straightforward. The problem is that each script then needs to check if there is a next script. This is ok but a minor mistake in a script and it becomes a debugging hell, especially if there are many scripts.

For this reason I was thinking to do it in a linear way. Having a main script (script1) keeping control of everything. The main issue is the `wait` part.

How do I make script1 to `pause` script2 until script3 has completed so that it cleans up?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to simply split each worker script in two parts: the real work and the cleanup.  Then your master script can run each of the scripts in sequence, followed by each of the cleanup scripts.

Another way to go about this would be to use a "build system" like [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), which may work well if you can define the inputs and outputs of each script as filenames and let SCons schedule the work and support the "clean" command.  This will be a bit of a steep learning curve, but for serious systems where debugging may be needed often, it may be more beneficial.

Comment: I would prefer to have a single file actually. I was thinking maybe there is a way to solve this with `trap`, `signal` or whatever to pause a script at a specific point..

Comment: So just move all your logic into functions in a single file.  Like `doit1()` and `cleanup1()` and so on.  Then call the `doit` functions in order followed by the `cleanup` functions in the opposite order.

Comment: Or instead of making scripts one can source bash libraries that has a job and cleanup subroutine.